# Orbital stability and inverse square law

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics, orbital-motion, stability

It is well-known that orbits are stable under an inverse square law gravitational attraction. My question is, how far could gravitational attraction deviate from an exact inverse square law without destabilizing orbits?  In particular, what bounds can theory place on the exponent of the distance relationship under the assumption of orbital stability?

Comment: Do you know [Bertrand's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_theorem)?

Comment: The exponential is precisely 2 or orbits aren't stable over time.

Comment: When the OP says “stable” he may not mean “closed”.

Comment: Thanks for Bertrand's theorem - that answers my question!